# Help with the limit of a function in the $\frac{0}{0}$ case

Tags: calculus, limits

The limit is this one:

> $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{(1+2x)^\frac{1}{x}-(1+x)^\frac{2}{x}}{x}$$

I have found that both $(1+2x)^\frac{1}{x}$ and $(1+x)^\frac{2}{x}$ tend to $e^2$, so the numerator tends to 0. I think that the book said that the result of this limit is $-e^2$ if I recall correctly.

Comment: can you use L'Hospital?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes, I can. I have tried applying L'Hospital, but the derivate of the numerator is pretty complicated and it lead me to nothing helpful

Comment: Limited expansions: for every $(a,b)$, $$(1+ax)^{b/x}=\exp(b\log(1+ax)/x)=\exp(ba-\tfrac12ba^2x+o(x))=e^{ab}(1-\tfrac12ba^2x+o(x))$$ hence $$(1+2x)^{1/x}-(1+x)^{2/x}=e^2(1-\tfrac12\cdot1\cdot2^2x-1+\tfrac12\cdot2\cdot1^2x+o(x))\sim-e^2x$$ hence the limit is indeed $-e^2$. Tools used: when $x\to0$, $$e^x=1+x+o(x)\qquad\log(1+x)=x-\tfrac12x^2+o(x^2)$$ and this is it!

Comment: @Did Sorry, but I don't understand that. I haven't learned about expansions yet, I'm still in high school.

Comment: @user416408 Please list the tools you are allowed to use.

Comment: @Did I only know basic calculus, like derivates, indefinite or definite integrals and limits. That's what I've been taught to date.

Comment: Can't you use Cesaro-Stolz or l'Hosital?

Comment: @theSongbird I can

Comment: What were your results when trying Cesaro-Stolz?

Comment: @theSongbird I don't think I can apply it. From what I know, Stolz-Cesaro is applied when the denominator is strictly monotone and divergent. I have only applied that theorem to limits of sequences, not functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that we use here two well known limits $$\lim _{ \quad x\rightarrow 0 }{ { \left( 1+x \right)  }^{ \frac { 1 }{ x }  } } =e\\ \lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { { e }^{ x }-1 }{ x }  } =1$$

> $$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 } \frac { (1+2x)^{ \frac { 1 }{ x }  }-(1+x)^{ \frac { 2 }{ x }  } }{ x } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 } \frac { { e }^{ \frac { 1 }{ x } \ln { \left( 1+2x \right)  }  }-{ e }^{ \frac { 2 }{ x } \ln { \left( 1+x \right)  }  } }{ x } =\\ =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 } \frac { { e }^{ \frac { 2 }{ x } \ln { \left( 1+x \right)  }  }\left[ { e }^{ \frac { 1 }{ x } \ln { \left( 1+2x \right)  } -\frac { 2 }{ x } \ln { \left( 1+x \right)  }  }-1 \right]  }{ x } =\\\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 } \frac { \left[ { e }^{ \frac { 1 }{ x } \ln { \left( 1+2x \right)  } -\frac { 2 }{ x } \ln { \left( 1+x \right)  }  }-1 \right]  }{ \frac { 1 }{ x } \ln { \left( 1+2x \right)  } -\frac { 2 }{ x } \ln { \left( 1+x \right)  }  } \cdot \frac { { e }^{ \frac { 2 }{ x } \ln { \left( 1+x \right)  }  } }{ x } \cdot \left[ \frac { 1 }{ x } \ln { \left( 1+2x \right)  } -\frac { 2 }{ x } \ln { \left( 1+x \right)  }  \right] =\\\ =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 } \frac { { e }^{ \frac { 2 }{ x } \ln { \left( 1+x \right)  }  } }{ x } \cdot \left[ \frac { 1 }{ x } \ln { \left( 1+2x \right)  } -\frac { 2 }{ x } \ln { \left( 1+x \right)  }  \right] =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 } \frac { (1+x)^{ \frac { 2 }{ x }  } }{ { x }^{ 2 } } \cdot \ln { \left( \frac { 1+2x }{ { \left( 1+x \right)  }^{ 2 } }  \right)  } =\\=\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 } (1+x)^{ \frac { 2 }{ x }  }\cdot \ln { { \left( \frac { 1+2x }{ 1+2x+{ x }^{ 2 } }  \right)  }^{ \frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 } }  } } =\\ =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 } (1+x)^{ \frac { 2 }{ x }  }\cdot \\\ln { { \left( 1+\frac { -{ x }^{ 2 } }{ 1+2x+{ x }^{ 2 } }  \right)  }^{ \frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 } }  } } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 } (1+x)^{ \frac { 2 }{ x }  }\cdot \ln { { \left[ { \left( 1+\frac { -{ x }^{ 2 } }{ 1+2x+{ x }^{ 2 } }  \right)  }^{ \frac { 1+2x+{ x }^{ 2 } }{ -{ x }^{ 2 } }  } \right]  }^{ \frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 } } \cdot \frac { -{ x }^{ 2 } }{ 1+2x+{ x }^{ 2 } }  } } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 } (1+x)^{ \frac { 2 }{ x }  }\cdot \frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 } } \cdot \frac { -{ x }^{ 2 } }{ 1+2x+{ x }^{ 2 } } =\color{red}{-{ e }^{ 2 }}$$

Comment: Wow! Extraordinary, thank you so much.

Comment: you are welcome)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with l'Hôpital. Consider $f_{a,b}(x)=(1+ax)^{b/x}$; then
$$
\log f_{a,b}(x)=b\frac{\log(1+ax)}{x}
$$
and so
$$
\frac{f_{a,b}'(x)}{f_{a,b}(x)}=b\frac{\frac{ax}{1+ax}-\log(1+ax)}{x^2}=
\frac{b}{1+ax}\frac{ax-(1+ax)\log(1+ax)}{x^2}
$$
Since you know that $\lim_{x\to0}f_{a,b}(x)=e^{ab}$, by a basic limit, we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}f_{a,b}'(x)
&=be^{ab}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{ax-(1+ax)\log(1+ax)}{x^2}\\
&=be^{ab}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a-a\log(1+ax)-a}{2x}\\
&=-\frac{ab}{2}e^{ab}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+ax)}{x}\\
&=-\frac{a^2b}{2}e^{ab}
\end{align}
Thus we have
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f_{2,1}(x)-f_{1,2}(x)}{x}=
\lim_{x\to0}\bigl(f_{2,1}'(x)-f_{1,2}'(x)\bigr)=
-2e^2+e^2=-e^2
$$

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm sorry, but I don't know what you mean by those a and b indexes.

Comment: @user416408 The function $(1+2x)^{1/x}$ is $f_{a,b}$ for $a=2$ and $b=1$. It's just a family of functions. Ease of computation: no need to do twice the same computations, as the other part is $f_{a,b}$ for $a=1$ and $b=2$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now.